# php resize image

Tags: php, image, resize

I have a class to read and output the image content, if $width is set, it will resize the image, and then output it.

If I call the function like this $image->readImage('123.jpg');  , it can output the image file correctly, but when I call $image->readImage('123.jpg', 300); to resize it, it just display a black image with resized width & height.

And I tried to replace the code from

```
@imagejpeg($thumb, null, 100);
```

to

```
@imagejpeg($image, null, 100);
```

will works~

-

```
protected function readImage($fileName, $width = 0) 
{
    if ($width <= 0) {
        return @file_get_contents($this->destination . '/' . $fileName);
    } else {
        $imageSize = @getimagesize($this->destination . '/' . $fileName);
        $actualWidth = $imageSize[0];
        $actualHeigth = $imageSize[1];

        if ($actualWidth <= $width) {
            return @file_get_contents($this->destination . '/' . $fileName);
        }
        $height = (100 / ($actualWidth / $width)) * .01;
        $height = @round($actualHeigth * $height);

        $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($this->destination . '/' . $fileName);
        $thumb = @imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        @imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $actualWidth, $actualHeight);

        ob_start();
        @imagejpeg($thumb, null, 100);
        $bits = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $bits;
    }
}
```

Any experts know what happened and help me to solve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you removed all the `@` symbols from in front of your function calls, you'd probably get a decent error message that might give you a clue.  Using `@` is a bad habit, unless you really really need it.

Comment: Your first paragraph is a little bit confusing since you claim that the same exact code does two different things...could you clarify what you mean when you say you call `$image->readImage('123.jpg');`?

Comment: I found that problem, my typo error, $actualHeight and $actualHeigth.

Sorry.

Comment: Ha ha, I spent 30 minutes one time trying to figure out an error where it told me the line number! After 30 minutes, my friend finally looked over and said, "You misspelled length...". I had spelled it "lenth" and couldn't figure it out...

Answer (score 8):

you've been inconsistant in your spelling of $actualHeight vs $actualHeigth

if you didn't have so many @ everywhere, then php would have told you this.

Comment: If you don't need them why are they there haohan?